# Restore Window Control in Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, titlebar, window-buttons

So I tested elementary OS
I don't like it so I removed it
I switch back to gnome but left me with elementary os style windows control. which has close in left and maximize in right.

I decided to run this command

```
gsettings set  org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'
```

Now it ruins everything. So, I probably just explain it in screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the current output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout`?

Comment: @pomsky ':minimize,maximize,close'

Comment: I reckon the issue is with the **Arc-Darker** GTK+ theme you're using. Try changing it to a default theme (like Adwaita).

Comment: @pomsky it works ! yeah ! not what I expected having to change it to the previous themes. But not so Annoying anymore, I love you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Terminal and run the following command to switch back to elementary OS default (close button on the left and maximise button on the right)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout close:maximize
```

or the following command to Ubuntu default (minimise, maximise and close on the right)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout :minimize,maximize,close
```

However, it seems the issue is with the Arc-Darker GTK+ theme that you're using. Change it to another theme (e.g. Adwaita) to fix the problem.